# R shiny updateCheckboxInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a R shiny application in which I have drop down box defined in `ui.R` as `lib` whose values are c("X","Y","Z") and also a check box called `spcheck` which is defined as

```
checkboxInput("spcheck","label1",value = FALSE))
```

Other conditions makes this checkbox available only when `input$lib=Z` and checking it would make few things appear.
When users select a different library, say X, I want to make the `spcheck` value `FALSE`, So I added the following code to `server.R`

```
observe({
          if (input$lib %in% c("X","Y") )  
          {cat("uncheck called 1 : ",input$spcheck,'\n')
           updateCheckboxInput(session,"spcheck","label1,value = FALSE)
           cat("uncheck called 2 : ",input$spcheck,'\n')
          }
          else return()                            
        })
```

The text displayed at console is :

```
 uncheck called 1 :  TRUE 
 uncheck called 2 :  TRUE
```

Why is it not making the spcheck value FALSE?
May be I'm missing something very trivial, but I couldn't figure it out.
Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it takes a few milliseconds since you tell shiny to update the input until it actually happens. When you call the update method, shiny has to send a message to JavaScript to change the value of the input, and once that's done, JavaScript sends a message back to R saying that the input has a new value. But the `input` variable does not change instantly when you make the call, it'll only have an updated value next time a reactive statement uses the `input$spcheck` variable

Comment: Is there a work around? to make it pause for few milli seconds or something?

Comment: It's a feature of the reactive programming design.  If you really want, you can either change the input yourself (after doing the update, do `input$spcheck <- TRUE` or something like that) or just add an observer that listens to a change in that input `observe({cat(input$spcheck)})

Comment: I am not sure `input$spcheck <- TRUE` is valid; you are likely to encounter:

`Attempted to assign value to a read-only reactivevalues object`

Comment: I wrote that comment in 2015 when I barely knew how shiny works. You're correct that this is not possible :)